# How can I decrease an li width when one of the li's is clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, html-lists

I want to decrease the width of Home and About `<li>` when the Contact is being clicked. Is it possible to use webkit for this or just plain java onclick and onfocus events? Im am trying to understand the is then else in CSS and HTML if there are any.

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this depending on what browsers you need to support and if you want to use a JavaScript framework to take away some of the pain albeit with the overhead of adding weight to the page by including said framework.

Here is a non-framework solution ([**demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/G9vuw/)) that works in IE9, Firefox and Chrome/Safari using [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener). For < IE9 support you would need to use slightly different event binding code - see the API link in the previous sentence.

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>​
```

#### CSS

```
li {
    width:100px;
    background-color:lightSkyBlue;
}

li.narrow {
    width:50px;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
// resize the list items apart from the one that is clicked
function resizeNotMe() {
    var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        if (listItems[i] !== this) {
            listItems[i].className = 'narrow';
        } else {
            listItems[i].className = '';
        }
    }
}

// create click events on the list items
function load() {
    var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        listItems[i].addEventListener('click', resizeNotMe, false);
    }
}

// run load function when page is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load, false);
```

Or you could use the more tightly bound [`element.onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick) approach which will run on more (older versions of IE) browsers but is not really the recommended approach any more since the *behaviour* (JavaScript events) are cluttering, or not separated from the *content* (HTML). [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is something web applications should strive towards.

[**demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/G9vuw/1/)

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="resizeNotMe(this)">Home</li>
    <li onclick="resizeNotMe(this)">About</li>
    <li onclick="resizeNotMe(this)">Contact</li>
</ul>​
```

#### CSS

Same as first solution

#### JavaScript

```
function resizeNotMe(me) {
    var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        if (listItems[i] !== me) {
            listItems[i].className = 'narrow';
        } else {
            listItems[i].className = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Or opt for a JavaScript framework (for example [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) which allows separation of concerns and provides a rich API for DOM and CSS manipulation, amongst other things.

[**demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/G9vuw/2/) (my preferred)

#### HTML

Same as first solution

#### CSS

Same as first solution

#### JavaScript

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('narrow').siblings().addClass('narrow');
});
```

The difference on this demo is the inclusion of the jQuery library so you would need to add something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to your code, or download jQuery and host it yourself.